# What is the difference between the codes for importing and calling Class from another dart.file (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, bloc

1) As you can see I'm practicing flutter bloc pattern. 
There are lots of imports here. What is difference between them? 
( package:bloc/bloc.dart)(bloc.dart)(package:test1/bloc.dart) 
test1 is my project name.
[image]

2) And I try to call Bloc Class which is in the bloc.dart file. But it says Bloc() isn't a function. What should I do?

also my bloc.dart file:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pratical difference between packages imports and relative imports, but packages imports are prefered for code legibility and organization. Also, relative imports tend to be a pain when you change a file from place and have to rename all the imports.

You "can" use both kinds of imports for the same file cause Dart treats them as 2 different namespaces but that will probably lead to bugs, probably that is what is causing your error.

Regarding the BLoC pattern, it seems that you are using a the pure core of BLoC, I recommend you to study the implementation of [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) (which is made by the BLoC team). It's the way that BLoC is used more often. There is also a great documentation by the BLoC team in [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted).